# Check if mouse cursor is within range of array with coordinates

Tags: javascript, arrays, canvas

I'm currently drawing a range of points on a canvas by using an array of coordinates.

```
var points =  [[102, 267], [254, 163], [343, 318], [522, 112], [610, 163], [681, 112]];

var canvas = document.getElementById('graph');
var c = canvas.getContext('2d');

function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
  var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
    x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
    y: evt.clientY - rect.top
  };
}

function drawPoints(){
  for (i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
    c.beginPath(); 
    c.arc(points[i][0], points[i][1], 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
    c.fillStyle = "black";
    c.fill();
  }
}
drawPoints();
```

I'm trying to write a function that recognizes these points and marks them as I mouseover the canvas.

```
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(evt) {
  var mousePos = getMousePos(canvas, evt);
  var currMouseX = mousePos.x;
  var currMouseY = mousePos.y;

  for (i = 0; i < points.length; i++){
    if ((points[i][0] >= currMouseX-4 && points[i][0] <= currMouseX+4) && (points[i][1] >= currMouseY-4 && points[i][1] <= currMouseY+4)) {
            console.log('in range of '+points[i]);
      c.beginPath(); 
      c.arc(points[i][0], points[i][1], 8, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
      c.fillStyle = "red";
      c.fill();
    }

  }
});
```

The problem I'm having is that I want to delete the marker when the mouse cursor leaves the range of the point.

If I set a simple `else` statement at the end, the loop only works for the last point in the array since, the rest of the for loop is still executed. I need to have a check that checks if the point has been hit, stop the for loop, check if the mouse has left the point range, if so, clear the canvas and redraw the points again.

Perhaps a loop is not the best way to handle this, maybe a needle/haystack aproach would work better, but I don't know how to implement this when searching for a range in stead of a single value inside nested arrays.

**[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/pafke/wzbj4L6g/2/)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically need a loop to redraw the canvas all the time:

```
setInterval(drawPoints, 1000 / 30); // redraw at 30 fps
```

Then you have to clear the canvas in your drawPoints:

```
function drawPoints(){
   c.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  for (i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
    c.beginPath(); 
    c.arc(points[i][0], points[i][1], 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
    c.fillStyle = "black";
    c.fill();
  }
}
```

Which leads to a new problem, the point only being red when you move the mouse. That's where you should change the `points` from an array of arrays to an array of objects:

```
points = [{x: 123, y: 234, hovered: false}];
```

And in drawPoints:

```
function drawPoints(){
   c.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  for (i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
    c.beginPath(); 
    c.arc(points[i].x, points[i].y, 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
    c.fillStyle = "black";
    if (points[i].hovered) {
      c.fillStyle = 'red';
    }
    c.fill();
  }
}
```

and finally you change your move function to toggle the `hovered` flag. I leave that piece of work to you.

Comment: That sounds resource intensive

Comment: but it's not resource intensive on the computer. you have that sort of loops running for every html/js game out there and they do that just fine.

Comment: I stumbled upon a sollution myself, check my answer. What would be the benefit of your answer over my own? ie. why use the setinterval timer?

Comment: Well, as an answer your's is okay but mine is more along the "industry standard" for creating interactive stuff.
Also, you want to separate things are good as you can, the mouseover just setting a flag and not having to bother about drawing anything is a good separation. Read about *entity component systems*, if you plan to extend this project. It will save you a lot of pain.

Comment: I do intend to extend this project. Will try your approach.

Answer (score 0):

I added a variable that stores wether the point was hit or not with a boolean. And I added a variable that stores the index of the point that was hit.

```
var checkHit = true;
var saveIndex = "";
```

Then I wrote another if statement that checks for the `checkHit` variable, if it is false, I check of the mouse cursor is still within range, of it's no longer in range, I redraw the canvas and reset the variables.

```
  if(!checkHit){
    if ((points[saveIndex][0] >= currMouseX-4 && points[saveIndex][0] <= currMouseX+4) && (points[saveIndex][1] >= currMouseY-4 && points[saveIndex][1] <= currMouseY+4)) {
        console.log('point stil in range');
    }
    else {
        c.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        drawPoints();
      checkHit = true;
            saveIndex = "";
      console.log('Redraw');
    }
  }
```

**[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/pafke/wzbj4L6g/4/)**

If anyone knows a less resource intensive method such as a needle/haystack approach, I'm open to suggestions/improvements.